# Can a ClickOnce project be configured so that downloaded file is called differently from setup.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'd like to make it so that when users click the "Install" button, the installer file they download to their local machine is called differently from default setup.exe, e.g. myCoolInstaller.exe. Is that even possible with ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup.exe file that is generated by Visual Studio has very little to do with ClickOnce. It simply bootstraps your pre-requisite installs together and launches your actual ClickOnce app (the .application file) when it's finished.

You should just be able to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to use symbolic links. From the command prompt, whilst in your release folder type:

```
mklink myCoolInstaller.exe setup.exe
```

Then everytime you publish to setup.exe, your users can download using the more friendly name. Note that this does not update the publish.htm file - you will need to edit that yourself. In our case, we don't use it - we provide a link to our customers directly to the installer .exe